# I want to put all the items of that were taken from a get api request in list format in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a get api and I want to get all the ID's that are present in it and put them in a list/array so I can use it in other api where I want to seperate even and odd elements from that list and pass it as a variables

The get api is something like
https://api.abs.com/contents

From this api I have taken the ID's using json extractor and stored them in id variable name.

Now I want to put all id elements into a list/array and seprate them into odd and even number and store in 2 variables(if possible provide the code how to seprate them as well)so I can pass them into a  post api in loop

How is this possible
Is there any way in Jmeter to do this..please help me out

Answer (score 0):

To do any sort of logic in JMeter, it's usually best to use a scripting sampler or pre/post-processor to implement a script with the logic. If you use a [JSR223_Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), you can import or run a [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) script.

For example your Groovy code to get the even or odd values and store them in a JMeter variable might look something like this:

```
// Get JMeter variables
def allValues = vars.get("valuesVariable")
def values = allValues.split(",")

// Apply groovy logic
def evenValues = values.findAll({ i -> (i as int) % 2 == 0 })
def oddValues  = values.findAll({ i -> (i as int) % 2 != 0 })

// Save as JMeter variables
vars.put("evenVariable", evenValues)
vars.put("oddVariable",  oddValues )
```